# Lazy loading property in Extension (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I know that swift doesn't allow declaring stored property within extension. And by the same token, lazily loaded properties are also prohibited. I know computed property is an alternative, but the task I have should only be executed once.

Is there any hack/alternative/overlooked way to mimic lazy var in extension?

Thanks!

Comment: The best course of action is probably using a function with the return type of the variable that you would create

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use computed property, combined with associatedObject. in this way, you can mimic a stored property. so the lazy var simulation will be:

```
// global var's address used as key
var #PropertyKey# : UInt8 = 0
var #varName# : #type# {
    get {
        if let v = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, & #PropertyKey#) as #type# {
            return v
        }else {
            // the val not exist, init it and set it. then return it

            // this way doesn't support nil option value. 
            // if you need nil option value, you need another associatedObject to indicate this situation.
        }
    }
    set {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, & #PropertyKey#, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a need for using such method? won't it give the same result if i just check if #varname# isn't nil? something like `var hi:String = { get { if let hi = hi { return hi } else { // init hi } } }`. Thanks!

Comment: you need a place to store property's value. computed property just encapsulate getter and setter method. it don't have a place to store a var. and associatedObject provide such a place. associatedObject will also ensure the object will get release when not needed. just like a true stored property. if you use the computed property in getter method, I think this will be a recursive circle and will use out stack.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't need to refer to `self` you can use a `static var`:

```
extension String {
    static var count = 0
    static var laughingOutLoud : String = {
        count++

        return "LOL: \(count)"
    }()
}

String.laughingOutLoud // outputs "LOL: 1"
String.laughingOutLoud // outputs "LOL: 1"
String.laughingOutLoud // outputs "LOL: 1"
```

(You don't need `count` in your implementation; that's just there to show it's only executed once.)

Comment: The memory it takes for static var `laughingOutOut ` is one single string to hold `LOL: \(count)` no matter how many instances I create. Thats the static work.  Am I right?